# 'TypeError: expected bytes, str found' when creating images dataset with Dataset API

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I'd like to create a TensorFlow's dataset out of my images using Dataset API. These images are organized in a complex hierarchy but at the end, there are always two directories "False" and "Genuine". I wrote this piece of code

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.data import Dataset
import os

def enumerate_all_files(rootdir):
    for subdir, dir, files in os.walk(rootdir):
        for file in files:
            # return path to the file and its label
            # label is simply a 1 or 0 depending on whether an image is in the "Genuine" folder or not
            yield os.path.join(subdir, file), int(subdir.split(os.path.sep)[-1] == "Genuine")

def input_parser(img_path, label):
    # convert the label to one-hot encoding
    one_hot = tf.one_hot(label, 2)
    # read the img from file
    img_file = tf.read_file(img_path)
    img_decoded = tf.image.decode_png(img_file, channels=3)
    return img_decoded, one_hot

def get_dataset():
    generator = lambda: enumerate_all_files("/tmp/images/training/")
    dataset = Dataset.from_generator(generator, (tf.string, tf.int32)).shuffle(1000).batch(100)
    dataset = dataset.map(input_parser)
    return dataset
```

However, when I run it in my terminal with

```
tf.enable_eager_execution()
# all the code above
d = get_dataset()
for f in d.make_one_shot_iterator():
    print(f)
```

it crashes with an error

```
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1306] Unknown: SystemError: <weakref at 0x7ff8232f0620; to 'function' at 0x7ff8233c9048 (generator_py_func)> returned a result with an error set
TypeError: expected bytes, str found  

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "lcnn.py", line 29, in <module>
    for f in d.make_one_shot_iterator():
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/iterator_ops.py", line 487, in __next__
    return self.next()
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/iterator_ops.py", line 518, in next
    return self._next_internal()
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/iterator_ops.py", line 508, in _next_internal
    output_shapes=self._flat_output_shapes)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_dataset_ops.py", line 1848, in iterator_get_next_sync
    "output_types", output_types, "output_shapes", output_shapes)
SystemError: <built-in function TFE_Py_FastPathExecute> returned a result with an error set
```

What am I doing wrong here?

**EDIT**
I tried running the code without calling `map`, `shuffle` and `batch` as well as commenting out the `input_parser` merthod but the error still appears.

**EDIT 2**
I changed `Dataset.from_generator` to `Dataset.from_tensor_slices` to see if the code for opening the pictures works. So the changed code looks like

```
def input_parser(img_path):
    # convert the label to one-hot encoding
    # one_hot = tf.one_hot(label, 2)
    # read the img from file
    img_file = tf.read_file(img_path)
    img_decoded = tf.image.decode_png(img_file, channels=3)
    return img_decoded

def get_dataset():
    dataset = Dataset.from_tensor_slices(["/tmp/images/training/1000010.png"]).map(input_parser).shuffle(1000).batch(100)
    return dataset
```

This works fine though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually changed the code from `Dataset.from_generator` to `Dataset.from_tensor_slices`. Final code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.data import Dataset
import os
tf.enable_eager_execution()

def enumerate_all_files(rootdir):
    for subdir, dir, files in os.walk(rootdir):
        for file in files:
            # return path to the file and its label
            # label is simply a 1 or 0 depending on whether an image is in the "Genuine" folder or not
            yield os.path.join(subdir, file), int(subdir.split(os.path.sep)[-1] == "Genuine")

def input_parser(img_path, label):
    # convert the label to one-hot encoding
    one_hot = tf.one_hot(label, 2)
    # read the img from file
    img_file = tf.read_file(img_path)
    img_decoded = tf.image.decode_png(img_file, channels=3)
    return img_decoded, one_hot

def get_dataset():

    file_paths = []
    labels = []

    for i in enumerate_all_files("/media/kuba/Seagate Expansion Drive/MGR/Spektrogramy/FFT/training/"):
        file_paths.append(i[0])
        labels.append(i[1])
    dataset = Dataset.from_tensor_slices((file_paths, labels)).map(input_parser).shuffle(1000).batch(100)
    return dataset

d = get_dataset()
for f in d.make_one_shot_iterator():
    print(type(f))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the error message, but I tried your code and it works for me if I do the input parser mapping before the batch and the shuffle operations:

```
def get_dataset():
    generator = lambda: enumerate_all_files("/tmp/images/training/")
    dataset = Dataset.from_generator(generator, (tf.string,tf.int32)).map(input_parser)
    dataset = dataset.shuffle(1000).batch(100)
    return dataset
```

Comment: I'm still getting an error, I checked the generator and it works as intended

Comment: That's strange, it works for me. All of my images are in the same directory so the generator always returns 'False' though. Tensorflow 1.9.0 here...

Comment: Oh, I changed the returned label to be either 0 or 1 instead of False or True. I also have Tensorflow 1.9

Comment: Still works for me. Can you verify that nothing is wrong with your images? Can you run `tf.read_file` and `tf.decode_png` for all the images in your directories?

Comment: The error still appears even without calling `map`, `batch` and `shuffle`

Comment: Updated my question